# How to edit Title in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I added " date " and " author " on my blog page. I see these 2 data are also on my Woocommerce single product pages. How can i remove it from Woocommerce only?

https://pixelkomando.com/ecran-benq-sw2700pt/ ( this is the blog )
https://pixelkomando.com/shop/paysages/hautes-fagnes/ ( this is a single product )